# Outlook web add-ins do not load as the Desktop Webviewer process dies

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

None of the web add-ins load for the user as the Desktop Web App Viewer process seems to end as soon as the add-in is opened.

How can we debug this further?

**User Setup**

- Browser: Microsoft Edge 80.0.361.62
- OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362. Build 18362
- Outlook: Microsoft Outlook for Office 365  MSO  (16.0.12430.20112) 32 bit

Comment: Is it possible to provide a dump of the crashing process?

Comment: I have the same issue reproducing on another client: Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO 16.0.13127.20266 32 bit

I will try to capture a dump